# How to map a model with an optional parent in NOSQL

Tags: sql, nosql

I'm in a situation where I have two entities in my database which I'm trying to convert to NOSQL. Site and Customer

1. A Customer has Sites
2. A Site can belong to a Customer but doesn't need one

I started thinking I would swap it around so I have a collection of Sites that can each have a customer but doesn't require one. But I still feel that Customer should be the parent as that seems more natural. However what would I do with sites without a customer in that case.

Is there a convention out there for dealing with this situation? I admit I'm still getting used to how things work in NOSQL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to me - Sites would be one thing by itself. People would be another by itself, and then you have a third thing - how do these People relate to these Sites

Comment: No people, just customers. So you wouldn't have them as part of the same collection. Two separate collections all together?

Comment: I would use just two documents: Customer and Site. Customer wouldn't care about having sites, but a site, when belonging to a Customer should have a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an object oriented database my suggestion would be to implement classes Site, Customer and SitePerCustomer like this

```
[Database]
public class Site
{
    ...
}

[Database]
public class Customer
{
     public IEnumerable<Site> ConnectedSites
     {
         get
         {
              return SQL<Site>("SELECT s.Site from SitePerCustomer s WHERE s.ConnectedCustomer=?", this);
          }
}

[Database]
public class SitePerCustomer
{
    public Site ConnectedSite;
    public Customer ConnectedCustomer;
}
```

Then you can use Customer for what it is and Site as well. The Customer instances can relate to all sites using a get property or method.